# NodeJS MongoDB Dynamic find() Query

Tags: node.js, express, mongodb-query

I am query mongodb for complete collection in a database by creating dynamic find query using request parameter in express nodejs.
But no result is found when queried.

```
const mongo=require('mongodb')
const MongoClient=mongo.MongoClient;
const assert=require('assert');
const express=require('express');
const app=express();
const http=require('http');

const url='http://127.0.0.1:27017';
const port='8000';
const host="localhost";

var server=http.createServer(app);
app.get('/:title',(req, res)=>{

    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, OPTIONS');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization');

    MongoClient.connect(url, (err, db)=>{
    var database=db.db('AppDatabase');

    var search=req.params.title;

    const query={"search":{search}};
    database.collection('testdata').find(query).toArray((err, result)=>{
        assert.equal(null,err);
        var data=JSON.stringify(result);

        res.send(data);
        db.close();
    });
    });
});   

server.listen(port, host,()=>{
    console.log("running");
});
```

expected result is a complete collection, and actual result is '[]'.

Comment: Your search query is `{ search: { search: req.params.title } }`, is this what you want? Can you show me structure of the documents in `testdata` collection? What version of mongodb npm package are you using?
If you are trying to filter by `title` property, you should change query to
`const query = { title: search };`

Comment: Can you please show us the `testdata` schema?

Answer (score 0):

Impossible to answer definitively without seeing the schema for your database. But I have a suspicion you do not have a dictionary key of "search", but should be "title". I would amend the code so that it looks like this:

```
var search=req.params.title;

const query={title:search};
```